# MS SQL Server trigger to add records in a table

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I am new to sql server and T-SQL. I have two databases (dbA and dbB) on a same microsoft sql server. These two databases have a table with exactly the same fields i.e. dbA.dbo.fldA, dbA.dbo.fldB, dbA.dbo.fldC, dbB.dbo.fldA, dbB.dbo.fldB and dbB.dbo.fldC. Whenever there is a new record added in dbA meeting a condition (e.g. dbA.dbo.fldC <> 0) , i want to have a trigger which automatically adds this record in dbB. But not the other way around, if a record is added in dbB it should not automatically be copied over to dbA.

This is my current trigger. But I am not sure how I should active it.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tradesToOps
   ON  dbInv.dbo.tblDatTradesToday
   AFTER  INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

     DECLARE @INSERT INT, @DELETE INT

    SET @INSERT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INSERTED)
   SET @DELETE = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DELETED)


    -- when Insert happens
    IF @INSERT = 1 AND @DELETE = 0
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO dbOps.dbo.tblDatTrades
        SELECT * FROM INSERTED

    END

   -- Insert statements for trigger here

END
```

Best,

Manu

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What have you tried so far?

Comment: From your question it appears that you do not understand how triggers work or how to create one, or the T-SQL statement that would conditionally insert records based on a Boolean predicate.  You simply create a trigger that does what you described above (using the appropriate T-SQL Insert statement). Read up on MSDN about triggers, and about T-SQL insert statements and T-SQL If statement.

Comment: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx

Comment: The main thing I would ask is **Why?** ... Why won't a view do? Why do you need to copy the data across?

Comment: I want the data to be copied across because we have two databases with one similar table. This can't be changed. I created a new trigger (see edited post). Where should I save this trigger so that it is always active?

Comment: You don't need to do this at all, you can query one from the other.

Answer (score -2):

please create the trigger like below

```
   CREATE TRIGGER TestTrigger1
    ON Person.Address
    AFTER INSERT
    AS

    INSERT INTO Test
        (col1)
    VALUES
        ('trigger fired');
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all, it's a snippet... if that.